# How to prove $A+I_n$ reversibility

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n$-order square matrix $A$ satisfy $A^m=A$,where $m$ is a positive even number.prove that $A+I_n$ reversibility.I want to use
$$(I_n+A)(I-A+A^2-\cdots+(-1)^{m-1}A^{m-1})=I_n+(-1)^mA^m.$$
But it felt like something was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only true if your coefficient field has characteristic $\neq 2$, which I will assume from now on.

Suppose that $A + I_n$ is not invertible. This means that it has non-trivial kernel, and hence there exists a nonzero vector $v$ such that $(A+I_n)v = 0$, or $Av = -v$.

Applying $A$ repeatedly, we see that $A^mv = (-1)^mv = v$ since $m$ is even.

However, we also have $A^m v = Av = -v$. We now have $2v = 0$, which leads to $v = 0$, a contradiction.

---

It is easy to see that the condition of characteristic $\neq 2$ is necessary for the question, as shown by the example $A = I_n$ over a field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: Thank you,the teacher's suggestion is to make up the factor method.what should I think...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what's the intended solution in the teacher's mind...